# Why am I getting the error 'self' used before self.init call in my struct?

Tags: swift

I've built this `struct` to handle a specific type of data I plan on using in some custom classes.
My issue is that featureSubSet variable is capable of being one of a few enums, and when this struct is initialized it wont know which enum it will be, so I declared it as Any.

When the public init is called, it will appropriately funnel the data to the needed private init method so that it can properly and fully be initialized.

I get the error at the end of the public init method, but I'm not sure how to get it to go away.

```
struct Feature {
//MARK: Variables needed for Feature
var featureSet: FeatureType
var featureSubSet: Any
var effect: String
var active: Bool?
var skill: Skill?
var ability: Ability?

public init(base: String, sub: String, effect: String, skill: Skill? = nil, ability: Ability? = nil) {
    switch base {
    case featureCategoryList()[0]: // Character Features
        self.init(CharacterFeature: sub, effect: effect)
    case featureCategoryList()[1]: // Combat Features
        self.init(CombatFeature: sub, effect: effect)
    case featureCategoryList()[2]: //Skill Features
        guard let newSkill = skill else {
            print("No skill")
            return
        }
        self.init(SkillFeature: sub, effect: effect, skill: newSkill)

    default:
        print("Somehow you picked something not on the list.")
        break
    }
}

private init(CharacterFeature sub: String, effect: String) {
    self.featureSet = .CharacterFeatures
    self.featureSubSet = CharacterFeatures.init(rawValue: sub)!
    self.effect = effect
}

private init(CombatFeature sub: String, effect: String) {
    self.featureSet = .CombatFeatures
    self.featureSubSet = CharacterFeatures.init(rawValue: sub)!
    self.effect = effect
}

private init(SkillFeature sub: String, effect: String, skill: Skill) {
    self.featureSet = .SkillFeatures
    self.featureSubSet = CharacterFeatures.init(rawValue: sub)!
    self.skill = skill
    self.effect = effect
}

//MARK: Feature functions
func string() -> String {
    //TODO: Make a string output for what the feature is.
    return ""
}
}
```

Comment: What error you are getting?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is an incorrect approach. If you find yourself storing something as `Any`, you're almost certainly on the wrong path. It's difficult to explore this code because it defines so many other types, but looking at it, it's unclear why you've needed `Any` here. `featureSubSet` is always of type `CharacterFeatures`. All the values of an enum are the same "type."

You have an error here:

```
    case featureCategoryList()[2]: //Skill Features
        guard let newSkill = skill else {
            print("No skill")
            return
        }
```

And here:

```
    default:
        print("Somehow you picked something not on the list.")
        break
    }
```

This returns without initializing `self` (and is probably your issue). If you can fail, then you need to make this an optional initializer (`init?`) or a throwing initializer, or you need to call `fatalError()` or similar crashing method on error. You can't just return without initializing.

I highly recommend that you redesign this, however. I don't see any reason that the parameters should be strings. Rather than passing in `"character"` and looking that up in some table, have the caller pass `.character` or `.combat` as an enum (you already have the enum).

Note in Swift 3, enum cases should always begin with a lowercase letter.

It's a little hard to understand what's going on in your code, but it doesn't really look like it should be a struct at all. It looks like an enum. Something like this:

```
enum CharacterFeature {
    // Features for characters
}

enum CombatFeature {
    // Features for combat
}

enum Skill {
    // skills
}

enum Effect {
    // effects
}

enum Feature {
    case character(CharacterFeature, Effect)
    case combat(CombatFeature, Effect)
    case skill(Skill, Effect)
}
```

Alternately, you could use a struct here, especially if there are more things that are shared by all features:

```
struct Feature {
    enum Kind {
        case character(CharacterFeature, Effect)
        case combat(CombatFeature, Effect)
        case skill(Skill, Effect)
    }

    let kind: Kind
    let effect: Effect
}
```

The key point is that you should generally work in explicit types, not strings. If you find yourself needing a too many optionals, you're often doing something incorrectly.

Comment: Great answer! I would only add the option to use `String`, as an enum *raw type*, if he needs to keep those (nasty!) strings around for other purposes — and he wants some control over the specified naming conventions used.

Comment: I actually completely agree. Thanks for the example. Unfortunately this error has been driving me nuts so I hadn't finished the switch statement and private init methods, but the reason I used Any as my data type for featureSubSet is because it is possible for it to be one of four different enum types. Using your alternative, how would you recommend dealing with initialization when getting the user's input? I was using the strings to filter it through the proper sequence of init methods to initialize it completely, what would be a better way to do this?

Comment: Generally the way to handle the user input is to make the enums `RawRepresentable` to `String`. So you initialize `Kind` using a string and then pass that to `Feature`. That's much more contained than passing a lot of strings to `Feature`. As you see, you avoid the `Any` using associated data on the enum. If you could give an example of the input data and what you want that to result in, I'm sure we can build an example.

Comment: Well, the user will be presented with three to four text fields. Two, or three depending upon the result of the first, will present a tableview via Popover to select an option. But one will have to be a string. Effect will eventually be a class that will take in a string and convert it to a formula for a die roll calculation. The first input will dictate the 'Kind' and the second will be 'Feature', if the 'Feature' is of certain types, it will give you another category to select from. So, the data types involved would be 2 to 3 enums, and a string. I'm not sure if this better explains it.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `featureCategoryList` is a `struct Feature` function, your original error:

> `self` used before `self.init` call

might be coming from this lines:

```
case featureCategoryList()[0]: 
    ...
case featureCategoryList()[1]:
    ...
case featureCategoryList()[2]:
```

since you are *implicitly* calling `self` before initialization.

After fixing the above error, you will *also* need to fix these as well:

> `self.init` isn't called on all paths before returning from initializer

Check out Rob's answer for some great alternatives.